# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

I got the following error message when I tried to create a Maven project in eclipse. Many have posted about proxies in settings.xml file and also flush the .m2 folder forcing it to download a new one. None of this is working for me. I'm at work, with proxy settings active in the internet options.

The error message:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloRESTEasy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

settings.xml:

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Comment: Your proxy should be commented, but it may just be a copy error. However, you pom.xml is really empty. Could you please post the full (even anonymized) one ?

Comment: **I face this issue and the solution i tried is clearing everything in .m2 folder from on OS and build the project gain from IDE**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it now. However it only is solved in Netbeans. Not sure why eclipse still won't take the settings.xml that is changed. The solution is however to remove/comment the User/Password param in settings.xml

Before:

```
      <proxies>
        <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>proxyuser</username>
          <password>proxypass</password>
          <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>
```

After:

```
      <proxies>
        <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>
```

Comment: Hi @JustinBieber,
Can i know the path for find out this settings.xml file? i am facing exception like "Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:" So i need to try this solution

Comment: Path to `settings.xml` :  `/c/Users/Username/.m2`

Answer (score 35):

Try cleaning the local `.m2/repository/` folder manually using `rm -rf` and then re build the project. Worked for me after trying every possible other alternative(reinstalling eclipse, pointing to the correct maven version in eclipse, proxy settings etc)

Comment: I just had to delete the folder `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin`. Still a +1 though.

Comment: Dont delete the whole respository directory. In my case i was having more then 600 mbs of jar. Only delete the conflicted jar. Once delete run maven clean and install.

Answer (score 19):

I was able to solve the same problem with different solution.

The solution that worked for me was to **Right click project "pom.xml" in eclipse** and select "**Maven Install**".

Comment: This works for me, but a little different: 1) delete .m2 directory, then right click project -> Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score 7):

Mainly this occurs during Eclipse upgrade.

I Solved using:

**-> Right Click Project-> Maven->Update Project-> Select all (checkbox)**

Old or out-dated, projects got refreshed with the updated jar files, and the required plugins. No more errors were visible.

Comment: too much easy and simple and works like charm for me

Answer (score 4):

For me, this problem occurs in Eclipse when the Maven installation is not well configured. By default the Maven installation is embedded in Eclipse. The `.settings.xml` file is set wherever the Eclipse installation points.

In my case this file was not auto-generated. I choose my own Maven installation - an external one. But if you don't explicitly choose where `settings.xml` is then Eclipse tries to get this file from the path set in the embedded installation. If the file is not autogenerated you have to choose the correct location.

Go to `windows/preferences/Maven/Installation/user settings` and choose the correct location of your `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the above error. I used Eclipse.

After followed the below solution, it works fine for me.

Solution is,

1. Right click project "pom.xml" in eclipse and select `Maven Install`.
2. Right click on the project -> Maven -> Update Project.
3. Refresh

Answer (score 3):

Right click project "pom.xml" in eclipse and select `Maven Install`.
Right click on the Project -> `Maven` -> `Update Project`.

Then Refresh.

Comment: Run as->Maven Install

Answer (score 3):

I have had this issue and I resolved it by following the next step:

1- Close Eclipse.

2- Go to user directory and delete the .m2 directory.

3- Open Elipse.

4- Right click on the project -> Run as -> maven install

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue, and removing the `.m2/repository/` has not solved it in my case. Seems that eclipse is unable to download the maven-plugin or dependency needed. Therefore you need to install it yourself.

I have finally solved it downloading both jar and pom files from the Maven Repository and installing it using the command (better than copying to the folder directly):
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>` 
(In my case: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=maven-war-plugin-2.2.pom -DpomFile=maven-war-plugin-2.2.pom`)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was: *CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 ....*

With eclipse luna from console in the pom.xml folder

```
mvn clean
mvn install
```

With Juno I had to had this to my pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

And then

```
mvn install
```

And then from eclipse right click>maven>update project 
* Once the plugin is donwloaded you can remove the plugin from your pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

**Jotting down some steps which help:**

*Writing answer from eclipse perspective as base logic will remain the same whether done by Intellij or command line*

1. Rt click your project -> Maven -> Update project -> Select Force update -> Click OK
2. Under properties tag , add :

> ```
> >  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
> > <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> ```

3. In some instance , you will start seeing error as we tried force update , saying , failure to transfer X dependency from Y path , resolutions will not be reattempted , bla bla bla
     **In such case quickly fix it by cd to .m2/repository folder and run following command :

> for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i**

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I used next way:

1.Added settings.xml file (~/.m2/settings.xml) with next content

```
     <proxies>
       <proxy>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>qq-proxya</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>passw</password>
          <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>
```

3. Using cmd go to folder with my project and wrote *mvn clean* and after that *mvn install* !
4. After that updated project in the Eclipse(Alt + F5) or right click on project -> Maven -> Update project

P.S. after that, when I add new dependency to my project I have to compile project using **cmd**(*mvn compile*). Because if I do it using eclipse plugin, I get error connecting with proxy connection.

Answer (score 1):

Force update works for me.
Select the force update option as per image in update maven project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, I follwed below three steps to solve,

1). check proxy settings in settings.xml refer,

2). .m2 diretory to release cached files causing problems

3) Point your eclipse to correct JDK installation. 
Refer [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra) to know how

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem... I follow the following steps...u can try it
1. Right click on maven project
2. Take cursor in Maven
3. Click on Update Maven project or (alt+F5).
it will take some time then most probably problem will solved..

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons, i fixed with following steps:

1. delete .m2 folder and re launch eclipse. (Find m2 folder in
   windows: **c:\Users\Your_User_Name\ .m2**
   or  to search in Mac : **~/.m2**
2. make sure settings.xml is configured as #JustinBieber mentioned.
3. provide settings.xml path in eclipse (windows->preferences->maven->user settings) **User Settings** must locate settings.xml file.

save changes and relaunch the eclipse..!! it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent i got solution:
Just clearing (.m2) complete folder and starting a new maven project problem solved for me.

**Note::** .m2 folder located in os installed disk only.
If you want the exact location, check in Eclipse:
Eclipse-->window-->preferences-->maven-->user settings
There local repository path is for .m2
Delete entire .m2 folder and restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had same issue while creating new spring project in eclipse using Maven.

The main reason for this issue is that the proxy settings was not there.

I used the following approach to reslove it:
1) create settings.xml with  the below content
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <usePluginRegistry/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers/>
      <mirrors/>
      <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>Your proxy</host>
            <port>Your port</port>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
    </settings>
2) Save the settings.xml file under local C:\Users\<<your user account>>\.m2
3) Then Right click project pom.XML in eclipse and select "Update Project". It always give precedence to settings.XML
```

Answer (score 0):

I have summarised what I did for my issue.

1. Delete .m2 folder.
2. Change the apache-maven-3.5.4\conf\settings.xml as follow

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyserver.company.com</host> --> Please change it according to your proxy
      <port>8080</port> -->Please change it accordingly
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

3. Try again in cmd. It will work.
4. For eclipse, delete the existing maven project and go to

   window ->prefernces -> maven -> user settings -> browse -> configure this path apache-maven-3.5.4\conf\settings.xml
5. Delete .m2 folder.
6. Restart the eclipse and try creating new maven project.

These steps worked for me.

Comment: I think that this does not provide any value to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your network is slow, so that jar isn't downloaded completely.

There are two methods:

a. find your .m2 folder, you can find some path like this 'org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin', you need only delete this foldler 'maven-resources-plugin', because others are downloaded well.

Then maven build your project.

If other problem occures, repeat this process again.

b. you can change a more quick maven source.

Firstly, you should find maven's settings file(window ->prefernces -> maven -> user settings). If it is empty, you can create a new one (any path, for example, .m2/settings).

Secondly, add sth like this (From https://blog.csdn.net/liangyihuai/article/details/57406870). This example uses aliyun's maven.

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    
      <mirrors>
        <mirror>  
          <id>alimaven</id>  
          <name>aliyun maven</name>  
<url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>  
          <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>          
        </mirror>  
      </mirrors>
    </settings>
```

Thirdly, maven build again. (before this, you should delete your .m2 folder's files)

Answer (score -1):

run:

```
mvn -U dependency:go-offline
```

It works for me.