# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, spring-boot

I am using eclipse mars-2. I want to create a new maven spring boot project in windows. But I'm getting error like

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 
  or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact 
  descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
  Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies 
  could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact 
  descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Would you please share the log using this command `mvn dependency:resolve -X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do the following steps. Sometimes it helps

1. Remove/Delete your `.m2/repository/` folder
2. Then run the following command `mvn clean install`
3. Then run `mvn build`

Resource Link: [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909466/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-jar-plugin)

Comment: thank you now, I have created the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the UDE like ECLIPSE or STS there generates a `.m2` folder with `settings.xml` in it.

After you install the mavan in your system you gonna get a settings.xml in it.

You just let the IDE know that it has to use the meven `settings.xml` which you can do it by deleting the `.m2` file in your users folder, clean and install.

Now you're good to go and enjoy writing your code!!!!