# Eclipse Maven build

Tags: maven, eclipse-kepler, maven-resources-plugin

I have installed Eclipse Kepler and tried to import my code. An error occurred while importing which I don't understand. The error was:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: Below links may help you to resolve your issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909466/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-jar-plugin/21932324

Comment: If you are just starting with Eclipse you should install the current version - Oxygen.2 (4.7.2), Kepler is 5 years old.