# pom.xml error, unable to find what is wrong in my pom.xml

Tags: pom.xml

[Screenshot of pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM7rg.png)I am starting with Spring Project. Have the below error in the pom.xml (Spring Tool Suite)

Started a new project using Spring Tool Suite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringInAction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringInAction</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

On the eclipse, a Big red Cross :).................................

Comment: can you please share the errors/screenshot  of that?

Comment: Nothing.. The code has run ..but a red cross in eclipse at pom.xml ( for the first line )

Comment: Screenshot link given above. At the start of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem resolve following these steps:

1. right click on your project
2. ***maven->update project***
3. then check

> Force update of Snapshots/Releases

4. ok

As I can't see your error details, instead,
in case that does not help: you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909466/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-jar-plugin/40912176#40912176)