# Apache Maven Error : Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom: 2.5 to central

Tags: maven, cas

I am new at this. I am working on apache maven. I am working behind a proxy server. Every time, I try to  build maven project. It gives me this error. I also changed proxy settings in settings.xml file. But It is not working. It keeps giving me same problem. Build Failure. I have searched for answer on net. But I could not find it. I am trying to integrate a CAS into my web applications and sites. If anybody also has suggestion for that please help me.
Edit:-
pom.xml file:-

```
  <proxies>
  <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
     <username>username</username>
      <password>pass</password>
      <host>companyhost</host>
      <port>8080</port>
     <!-- <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>-->
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
```

error:-

```
C:\workspace\local-cas>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building local-cas 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/mave
-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-20T17:03:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its de
endencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apa
he.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.ap
che.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.mave
.apache.org/maven2): Connect to host.com:8080 failed: Conection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swi
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please re
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolut
onException
C:\workspace\local-cas>
```

---

I think that I am getting problem because everything is restricted due to company proxy server.

Comment: Can you post the full error message and your pom file as well as your settings.xml file?

Comment: Post Error message stating reason for Build Failure

Comment: do u see any error indication i.e red mark on POM?

Comment: @OpenJDK- I have updated my answer.Look at it. I have also uploaded pom.xml and error.

Comment: @OpenJDK- No, I don't see any error indication on POM.

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579247/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up a maven proxy in your `settings.xml` properly.

Have a look (for example) in your web browser and see how it is set up.

From the documentation on [Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html):

```
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Better ask your colleague for working proxy. No company will block this thing

Comment: Thanks. I already setup the proxy but it still gives the same error. Could there be any other reason for that?

Comment: As per my understanding this problem must be related with your proxy

Comment: "No company will block this thing" I worked for a company with very strict IT that blocked Maven. Perhaps it should be no sensible company.