# Failed to execute goal on project Could not resolve dependencies for project Failed to collect dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm having issues with build and I'm getting `Failed to execute goal on project` error. I see two errors I think? What does each one of these mean?

1. `Could not resolve dependencies for project`
2. `Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.axis:axis:pom:1.4 from/to central (http://ABC:9090/artifactory/repo): Error transferring file: No route to host` This I think means a proxy issue, the build box can not connect to outside to pull in the dependency?

I have checked the following for both of these to no avail:

- https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXVLjSAO/maven-error-failed-to-collect-dependencies-when-trying-to-run-the-process
- [Apache Maven Error : Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom: 2.5 to central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038262/apache-maven-error-could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven) (There is no proxy for this)
- [Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor) (Seems to be for IDE, this is is pipeline)

Any assistance would be appreciated on this, Thank you.

Build Log:

```
18:35:32.620 [go] Job Started: 2020-08-23 18:35:32 UTC

18:35:32.620 [go] Start to prepare PATGUI-build/111/Execute_Script/1/build_job on example.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent2]
18:35:32.639 [go] Start to update materials.

18:35:32.639 [go] Start updating files at revision 457cd11e9364709d8ace42d3d78dac4d9427dd8f from git@github.comcast.com:example
18:35:32.711 [GIT] Fetching changes
18:35:33.841 STDERR: From github.comcast.com:example
18:35:33.841 STDERR:    1d4af3e..457cd11  20.08_OMS_15.09XXX -> origin/20.08_OMS_15.09_Endpoint
18:35:33.850 [GIT] Performing git gc
18:35:33.856 [GIT] Reset working directory pipelines/PATGUI-build
18:35:33.856 [GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy
18:35:34.042 [GIT] Cleaning submodule configurations in .git/config
18:35:34.153 [GIT] Updating working copy to revision 457cd11e9364709d8ace42d3d78dac4d9427dd8f
18:35:34.258 HEAD is now at 457cd11 Adding rpc dependency
18:35:34.258 [GIT] Removing modified files in submodules
18:35:34.560 [GIT] Updating git sub-modules
18:35:35.166 [GIT] Cleaning unversioned files and sub-modules
18:35:35.166 [GIT] Git sub-module status
18:35:35.329  51c608012d468edce285f7e60084b5dfa8e87a7a trunk (PAT-9.10@79-997-g51c6080)
18:35:35.330 [GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy
18:35:35.479 [go] Done.

18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_SERVER_URL' to value 'https://example.comcast.net:8154/go'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_TRIGGER_USER' to value 'cdvprov'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_NAME' to value 'PATGUI-build'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER' to value '111'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_LABEL' to value '111'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_NAME' to value 'Execute_Script'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_COUNTER' to value '1'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_JOB_NAME' to value 'build_job'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '457cd11e9364709d8ace42d3d78dac4d9427dd8f'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_TO_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '457cd11e9364709d8ace42d3d78dac4d9427dd8f'
18:35:35.480 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_FROM_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '457cd11e9364709d8ace42d3d78dac4d9427dd8f'

18:35:35.490 [go] Start to build PATGUI-build/111/Execute_Script/1/build_job on example.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent2]
18:35:35.490 [go] Current job status: passed.

18:35:35.490 [go] Start to execute task: Plugin with ID: script-executor.
18:35:35.494 [script-executor] OS detected: 'Linux'. Is Windows? false
18:35:35.501 [script-executor] Script written into '/app/go-agent2/pipelines/example/4f66c2c3-2733-4b11-9142-8f857881a0d7.sh'.
18:35:35.508 +++ date +%m
18:35:35.510 ++ BUILD_MONTH=08
18:35:35.511 +++ date +%m
18:35:35.514 ++ echo BUILD_MONTH=08
18:35:35.516 +++ cat pom.xml
18:35:35.521 +++ cut -d '<' -f1
18:35:35.521 +++ grep '<version>'
18:35:35.523 +++ cut -d '>' -f2
18:35:35.524 +++ head -1
18:35:35.530 ++ APP_VERSION=20.08
18:35:35.532 +++ cat pom.xml
18:35:35.535 +++ grep '<sprintNumber>'
18:35:35.537 +++ head -1
18:35:35.537 +++ cut -d '>' -f2
18:35:35.539 +++ cut -d '<' -f1
18:35:35.543 ++ SPRINT_NUMBER=01
18:35:35.543 ++ PATCH_NUMBER=111
18:35:35.543 ++ echo APP_VERSION=20.08
18:35:35.543 ++ echo PATCH_NUMBER=20.08.01.111
18:35:35.544 ++ /app/platform/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DbuildNumber=111 clean install
18:35:38.540 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
18:35:38.859 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:38.859 [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
18:35:38.859 [INFO] 
18:35:38.859 [INFO] PortOut
18:35:38.859 [INFO] PortOutWeb
18:35:38.859 [INFO] PortOutApp
18:35:38.861 [INFO]                                                                         
18:35:38.861 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:38.861 [INFO] Building PortOut 20.08
18:35:38.861 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:39.159 [INFO] 
18:35:39.159 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ PortOut ---
18:35:39.417 [INFO] 
18:35:39.417 [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ PortOut ---
18:35:39.840 [INFO] Installing /app/go-agent2/pipelines/PATGUI-build/pom.xml to /app/home/go/.m2/repository/com/comcast/ets/tpp/portout/PortOut/20.08/PortOut-20.08.pom
18:35:39.920 [INFO]                                                                         
18:35:39.920 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:39.920 [INFO] Building PortOutWeb 20.08
18:35:39.920 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:41.432 Downloading: http://example.net:9090/artifactory/repo/org/apache/axis/axis/1.4/axis-1.4.pom
18:35:44.642 
18:35:44.650 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/axis/axis/1.4/axis-1.4.pom
18:35:45.311 
18:35:45.321 Downloading: http://example:9090/artifactory/repo/javax/xml/rpc/javax.xml.rpc/1.1.0-20081006/javax.xml.rpc-1.1.0-20081006.pom
18:35:48.444 
18:35:48.449 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/rpc/javax.xml.rpc/1.1.0-20081006/javax.xml.rpc-1.1.0-20081006.pom
18:35:48.456 
18:35:48.547 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:48.547 [INFO] Reactor Summary:
18:35:48.547 [INFO] 
18:35:48.547 [INFO] PortOut ........................................... SUCCESS [1.058s]
18:35:48.547 [INFO] PortOutWeb ........................................ FAILURE [8.624s]
18:35:48.547 [INFO] PortOutApp ........................................ SKIPPED
18:35:48.547 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:48.547 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
18:35:48.547 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:48.547 [INFO] Total time: 10.052s
18:35:48.547 [INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 23 18:35:48 UTC 2020
18:35:48.733 [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/103M
18:35:48.733 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:35:48.749 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PortOutWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.comcast.ets.tpp.portout:PortOutWeb:war:20.08: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.beehive:beehive-controls:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-ejb-control:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-jdbc-control:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-jms-control:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-netui-compiler:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-netui-tags:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.apache.beehive:beehive-netui-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4 (compile), commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0 (compile), commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4 (compile), commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 (compile), commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3 (compile), commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6 (compile), commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.5 (compile), commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0 (compile), commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0 (compile), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (compile), commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4 (compile), commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.4 (compile), com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.0 (compile), apache-oro:jakarta-oro:jar:2.0.7 (compile), javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 (compile), com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.3 (compile), javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile), javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4 (compile), javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1 (compile), oro:oro:jar:2.0.8 (compile), org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6 (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.5.6 (compile), taglibs:standard:jar:1.0.6 (compile), javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2 (compile), struts:struts:jar:1.2.7 (compile), velocity:velocity-dep:jar:1.4 (compile), com.comcast.ets.tpp.portout:oms-service-client:jar:12.10 (compile), com.comcast.ets.tpp.portout:npac-service-client:jar:1.0 (compile), pat.weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.3 (provided), weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.3 (provided), weblogic:weblogic-controls:jar:9.2 (compile), weblogic:weblogic-netui:jar:9.2 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (provided), weblogic:wlw-system:jar:9.2 (compile), weblogic:wlcommons-logging:jar:9.2 (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:jar:1.18.1 (compile), org.json:json:jar:20160212 (compile), oracle.jdbc:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4 (compile), org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4 (compile), javax.xml.rpc:javax.xml.rpc:jar:1.1.0-20081006 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.axis:axis:pom:1.4 from/to central (http://example:9090/artifactory/repo): Error transferring file: No route to host -> [Help 1]
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] 
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] 
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] 
18:35:48.750 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
18:35:48.750 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :PortOutWeb
18:35:48.781 [script-executor] Script completed with exit code: 1.
18:35:48.804 [go] Current job status: failed.

18:35:48.808 [go] Start to create properties PATGUI-build/111/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b2p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent2]
18:35:48.809 [go] Start to upload PATGUI-build/111/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b2p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent2]
18:35:50.682 [go] Uploading artifacts from /app/go-agent2/pipelines/PATGUI-build/PortOutApp/target/PortOutApp-20.08.01.107.ear to target/
18:35:52.489 [go] Uploading artifacts from /app/go-agent2/pipelines/PATGUI-build/build-vars to target/
18:35:52.543 [go] Job completed PATGUI-build/111/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b2p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent2]
```

Comment: The issue `Error transferring file: No route to host`... network/firewall/proxy etc.

Comment: Check out if you can reach that repository from the host. Try to configure the proxy in the settings.xml https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Ok, I have tried moving the jars into our artifactory and no luck so far, I'll will take a further look. Still getting the same error.