# Maven Build is not creating executable jar file

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, executable-jar

I am trying to create an executable jar file of my maven project.

Here is my POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jpg.to.pdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>JpgToPdf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.so.JpgToPdf</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here are the commands I tried so far without any luck.

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
mvn clean compile assembly:assembly
mvn -e -cpu,--check clean compile assembly:assembly
mvn -e -cpu,--check clean compile assembly:single
mvn clean compile assembly:single -U
```

Here is the console output of the last command.

```
E:\Projects\Personal\Workspaces\PracticeWorkspace\JpgToPdf>mvn clean compile assembly:single -U
857 [DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
863 [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
864 [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
867 [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
870 [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
876 [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
877 [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
879 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
881 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
883 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
884 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
886 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
887 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
889 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
889 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
890 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
891 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
893 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
894 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
895 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
896 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
897 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
898 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
899 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
900 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
901 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
902 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
903 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
904 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
905 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
907 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
908 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
909 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
910 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
911 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
912 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
914 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
914 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
916 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
917 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
918 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
919 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
920 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
921 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
923 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
926 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
930 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
931 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
933 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
936 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
938 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
941 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
946 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
948 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
951 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
952 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
955 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
956 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
960 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
961 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
964 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
965 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
968 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
969 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
970 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
971 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
973 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
975 [DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
980 [DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
1027 [DEBUG] Message scheme: color
1028 [DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
1034 [DEBUG] Reading global settings from E:\Projects\Personal\Required\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
1037 [DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\settings.xml
1054 [DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from E:\Projects\Personal\Required\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
1057 [DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\toolchains.xml
1067 [DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\repository
1088 [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\repository
1100 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
1154 [DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.jpg.to.pdf:JpgToPdf:jar:0.0.1: (none)
1156 [DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
1174 [DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix assembly from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
2405 [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
2410 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 via 172.18.65.22:80 with username=, password=***
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/3.7.0/maven-assembly-plugin-3.7.0.pom
3322 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-assembly-plugin\3.7.0\maven-assembly-plugin-3.7.0.pom.lastUpdated
3385 [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
3394 [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
3397 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 via 172.18.65.22:80 with username=, password=***
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/3.7.0/maven-assembly-plugin-3.7.0.jar
3863 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Varun.Jain\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-assembly-plugin\3.7.0\maven-assembly-plugin-3.7.0.jar.lastUpdated
3876 [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.7.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
4476 [DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix assembly to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin from POM com.jpg.to.pdf:JpgToPdf:jar:0.0.1
4481 [DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:pom:3.7.0, already updated during this session.
4484 [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
4490 [DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0, already updated during this session.
4496 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
4500 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
4500 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
4506 [INFO] Total time:  3.438 s
4507 [INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-04T15:36:06+05:30
4510 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
4514 [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
4522 [ERROR]
4522 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
4525 [ERROR]
4526 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
4532 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Answer is already available : checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579247/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Try to change the plugin version. according to mvn repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) there is no jar with version 3.7 exists

Comment: Thanks for the info @lazy.coder.  You can post it and I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the plugin version. According to mvn repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin), there is no jar with version 3.7 exists

Answer (score 0):

Change your maven assembly plugin to 3.7.1. Here is list of available plugins: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-management.html