# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Tags: java, maven, plugins, netbeans

Not able to create a maven web application in netbeans

How to resolve it. Why this error is showing

Comment: Please provide more informations. Did you try anything from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579247/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download maven first([Maven Download Link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)), and then configure the basic settings of maven.For specific configuration, Please refer to [Maven Best Practices](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/MavenBestPractices.html).

Comment: This is not correct. Maven is integrated with NetBeans, so downloading it is completely unnecessary unless you want to use a specific version for some reason, and that clearly is not relevant in the question being asked.